# oracle query - something similar to pivot, but

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table like this:

```
ID_ORIG    ID_DEST       DISTANCE  
-------    -------      --------  
1          101          10              
1          102          15  
1          103          20  
2          101          25  
2          102          30  
2          103          35  
3          101          40  
3          102          45  
3          103          50
```

And I want the following result:

```
ID_ORIG     101         102         103
-------     ---         ---         ---
1           10          15          20
2           25          30          35
3           40          45          50
```

I tried to use 'pivot', but obiously didn't achive this result. Database is Oracle 11g.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your pivot query and the results it gave you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
select * From(
    select * from YourTable
  ) PIVOT (sum(DISTANCE) for (ID_DEST) IN (101, 102, 103));
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/edec1/1)